# Is there a way to create a second container bound script from a Spreadsheet without making a copy of the first one?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

I can't find any way to make another container bound project for Spreadsheet without first copying the original and then closing both and returning to the spreadsheet, going to extensions and clicking apps script and then click on create another project.  Is there not a way to create another project without first copying the current project?

After Tanaike's suggestion I created a new project in the same container but that lead to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77310139/why-do-i-get-this-error-cannot-call-spreadsheetapp-getui-from-this-context)

Comment: You want to add a new Google Apps Script project of the container-bound script type to Google Spreadsheet even when a container-bound script already exists. You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script. If my understanding of your question is correct, I think that your goal can be achieved by [Method: projects. create of Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create). As a simple test, you can test it with "Try this method" of the API. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: No actually I was just trying to find a way to do it from the User Interface.  But yeah I guess I could do it that way too.  There used to be a way to do it in the old editor.  But the only way I can see to do it now is to create a copy and once you have two projects they provide the link to create another.  It seems like a stupid way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you wanted to achieve your goal with the UI without a script. In this case, I'm worried that the current IDE might not be able to directly achieve this. From this situation, I thought that the method for using "Try this method" of the Google Apps Script API might be a workaround. I apologize that I cannot propose a clear answer.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I'll try it and it to my scripts that backup all of my scripts into ascii text files, which should have been provided to everyone a long time ago.

Comment: I did it right from API explorer and it works just fine.   Thanks for you help.  I've really learned a lot from carefully studying your answers.  I especially appreciated learning how to use reduce more effectively.

Comment: Thank you for replying and honored about it. As another approach, although it is required to prepare, when a Google Apps Script project linked with the Google Cloud Platform project is deployed as the Web Apps, after this preparation, when it simply accesses the Web Apps URL with the query parameter, a new Google Apps Script project of the container-bound script can be created. In this case, the Web Apps is used as the wrapper API of Google Apps Script API.

Comment: I thought Tanaikes suggestion woujld be okay but may be not [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77310139/why-do-i-get-this-error-cannot-call-spreadsheetapp-getui-from-this-context)