# Why do I get: "Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context", when calling from the script editor, with two container bound projects?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ide

**Works when running from menu.  Doesn't work when running from script Editor with two bound projects**

> Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. at getProjectFileAndFunctionNames(GASAPICode:274:18)

I wrote the script a few days ago and it's been running as a dialog just fine.  In fact when I call from the menu it works  fine but if I call it from the script editor I get the error.  This wasn't happening yesterday and the only significant thing that I have done is to add another project to the container.  I tried closing the file and reopening it, but no effect.

So I removed the other project since there was nothing in it except for a blank function and minimal manifest.  After deleting the other project I closed the file and reopened it.  When I opened the script editor and ran the script it ran fine.  Anyone have an explanation for that?

Comment: I got curious and replicated this issue, it seems that the error most likely happens when both project files are open or executed simultaneously. For some reason, it seems like the project isn't being detected as a bound script. You might consider filing a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905) for this.

Comment: As far as I know I could not open them at the same.  It's a one or the other deal.  And the second project only one function that did nothing.

Comment: I'm working on another project I'll return to this and try to make it happen with another less import container